# to add to Debian or to remove from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

Is it possible for someone to suggest: at a general level, what are the pros and cons of installing software (and perhaps configurations) on Debian that come with say Ubuntu or Kali *versus* uninstalling software (and perhaps reconfiguring) say Ubuntu to get some advantages of Debian?

Should I worry that installing some software that comes with Ubuntu on Debian might cause trouble? (edit: answered)

How do I know what relevant software is available for Ubuntu, but not Debian? (edit: [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742803/compare-software-available-for-debian-stable-vs-ubuntu-lts-to-work-with-data))

My interests are in working with data.

I am new to Linux (not bash) and have already just installed Debian but am reconsidering my strategy--whether to shift to Ubuntu--before I go on from here.

Comment: If you use the package manager, it will cause trouble, because of unmet dependencies. If you need newer versions of only few software and for the rest want to keep stability, stay with Debian and try `flatpak` for these. Or go with Ubuntu minimal install, then you don't need to uninstall much.

Comment: @pLumo thanks a lot. I dont believe I need to have the most recent software versions. But I suspect there are much software (for data analysis, programming, database, data analysis package control/docker containers, and so on) of perhaps older versions that comes with Ubuntu but not on Debian.

Comment: Kali recommends not mixing its repositories with Ubuntu's. The actual [document](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) suggests that putting Kali repositories on a Ubuntu system will eventually break the installation. Putting a Ubuntu repository on a Kali system will definitely  break the system. Also, Kali is explicit that it is not for people new to Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use packages that are available on Ubuntu but not on Debian, you should use Ubuntu.

Ubuntu (and Kali, but I’ll ignore that because it assumes familiarity with Linux) is based on Debian, but it is not necessarily compatible with Debian. Its core assumptions aren’t necessarily the same as Debian’s, so while it uses the same packaging format and many of the same packages, they may have different expectations, and different (undeclared) dependencies. Even the common packaging format can run into difficulties: for example, Ubuntu packages can now be compressed with `zstd`, but such packages can’t even be extracted in Debian releases before the forthcoming release 12.

You can always take the source of a package from Ubuntu and Kali and rebuild it on Debian, but you might not be particularly comfortable with that.

Comment: Cheers Stephen. Undeclared dependencies and packaging formats may cause trouble, I see, very good to know. Does any immediate knowledge come to your mind as to whether and how to get some advantages of Debian on Ubuntu? For example; privacy, no advertisement, stability, minimalism?

Comment: @Johan_A privacy? No advertisement? What do you mean? How is Ubuntu less privacy oriented than Debian? And what advertisement? They did have a misguided deal with Amazon some years ago but that is no longer the case, if I remember correctly, and hasn't been for a few years. Do they now do some kind of data sharing? And what kind of minimalism? On which flavor of Ubuntu? Basically, please post this as a new question, explaining your concerns and what you would like to have. If you already have Debian, and mostly work on data, I doubt you'd see a benefit in switching to Ubuntu.

Comment: @terdon thanks for your comment. I will consider asking another question. You may also consider writing an answer to my question, as you seem to conclude differently than Stephen, that is, to go with Debian rather than Ubuntu. I see my question may lead to opinionated answers, because I have not specified more clearly, what data software I would like to use. What regards the aforementioned privacy, no ads, stability, and minimalism; these are concerns I have stumbled upon through google. But they might not be valid, as you suggest - and thanks for that :-)

Comment: @Johan_A Stephen isn't recommending either Ubuntu or Debian, he is simply saying that if you want to have an Ubuntu package, then you should use Ubuntu. He is saying that what you should _not_ do is try and bring in packages from one distribution and install them on another. Both Ubuntu and Debian are almost certainly fine for what you want to do, it is only if you really need an Ubuntu package that you should use Ubuntu and not try to install the Ubuntu package on Debian.

Comment: @terdon, I agree

Comment: @StephenKitt, do you mind adding to your answer a judgment on the security and ease of installing such non-Debian-repo-software from source versus from package managers like `flatpak` that pLumo suggested in his above comment? (alternatively, I may post a new question).

Comment: @Johan_A that’s a rather different question, and it doesn’t seem to fit within the scope of your initial question here; so you’d be better off asking a new question.